# Proper way to create custom Access Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I was wondering (and I know it depends on the project and what not) what is the best/proper way of developing a custom access table where the admin can fine grain access to the site. Is it basically creating a bunch of roles dynamically and checking for those roles using the [Authorize] attribute? one problem I see with this (and I might be wrong since I just started learning the asp.net MVC architecture) is that in order to modify access I would have to change and recompile the whole site.

What I'm looking for is to present the admin with a set of actions and have them pick and choose what each user (and/or role, where role can be something different than the simplemembership roles if that would be better) can and can not do in the site (anywhere from accessing a particular action to making a change to the name property of entity1 for example)

Anyone has a suggestion of a tutorial or some sort of plugin or even a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the authorization pattern: upon authentication a users id AND her assigned roles are to be attached to the thread context in an iprincipal. This principal is then checked against your software when you do security checks in your code.

There is therefore nothing that needs to get recompiled, unless you want to change which roles are allowed to do what. And then only for the places you have done programmatic checks. Access to url paths can be defined in the web.config.